# create pd df with index 0 to 5 and columns x1 to x55. values with the index  and with the column "colj" should be 9×+

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I don't know how to adjust the elements of the data frame with the condition of  9×+

This is what I have. Help!

```py
dt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10), columns = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'], index = [0 , 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5])
dt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

i will make `m row` X `n col` dataframe.**(answer is 3row X 4col)**

you can make 6 X 55 dataframe by modifying `m`, `n`

at first make 3 X 4 dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
m, n = 3, 4
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(0, m), columns=range(1, n + 1))
```

`df`

```
    1   2   3   4
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0
```

make desired output

```
out = df.add(df.columns).add(df.index * 9, axis=0).add_prefix('x')
```

out

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4
0   1   2   3   4
1   10  11  12  13
2   19  20  21  22
```